# Examples to clarify Storage vs Memory assignments / return parameters

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

Is there a mistake in funcB? I do not understand why/when to mention the variable name of the return parameter in the function signature.

```
contract Foo {

    // State variables go to Storage
    uint[] public foo;  

    function funcA(uint[] x) public returns (uint) { // x is in memory
        foo = x  // x is copied to storage now

        uint a = 100  // a is in storage
        return a
    }

    function funcB(uint[] x) public returns (uint a) { // x is in memory
        a = 100  // a is in memory? because `returns (uint a)`
        return a
    }
}
```

Also, I suppose funcA is incorrect but funcB is okay in the following example?

```
contract Foo {

    uint[] public foo;  

    function funcA() public returns (uint[]) { 
        uint a[];
        // push stuff to a
        return a
    }

    function funcB() public returns (uint a[]) {
        // push stuff to a
        return a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the return variable name is useful in case you want to return multiple results from a function.

for example:

```
function funcA() public returns (uint a,unit b,uint c){
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3; 
}
```

this will output 3 return values.

Answer (score 0):

in this case a is in memory. 
You can handle your return in TWO ways

```
function funcB(uint[] x) public returns (uint a) { // x is in memory
    uint z = 100;
    return z; // or return 100 directly 
}
```

or

```
function funcB(uint[] x) public returns (uint a) { // x is in memory
    a = 100;  // you have already assigned a to be 100
    return;
}
```